# Creating Dynamic list in android?

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

i want like used listview in android and i want to create dynamic list like   below image.how to possible and i want to fix top toolbar and below toolbar .

Thanks!!!
    [image]

Comment: Have you tried any thing? Please put your code which is not working or having some problem.

Comment: do as Ankit said .... no one write the design code for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for three keywords: custom listview, adding search button to actionbar and adding a tab bar.

1) For your custom listview you need to create a layout for each row. You could realize it with a simple nested `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` for the following parts. I could highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/). Just modify the layout to create a row for your snippet:

[image]

2) For the search button in the actionbar, check out [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) of the Android developer guide. This should help you getting started.

3) A tab bar example can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) or [here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html).

Hope it helps you getting started.

Answer (score 0):

For the list: Create a layout xml and a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) that knows how to inflate the layout and populate it with each list item's data. Doing a quick google I found this [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1pD-a56U8IqXY1YBx4RsKaKFaJ6MA6N-N7NH1ud3DGAw/edit#slide=id.g237dfa24_0_21) on it that looks to be fairly comprehensive.

For the top and bottom bar: Look at the [action bar developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

As has already been said, nobody will write your code for you. But this stuff should enable you to learn how to do it yourself.